# Excel VBA script rounding a sum of integers (...and i didn't ask for it)

Tags: excel, vba, sum, integer, rounding-error

Already had a lot of help from you guys trough other people's questions, but can't find an answer for this one. So the time came for asking a question here myself.

Got a fairly easy VBA script for listing some costs and payment of those costs. In it i have something called a "UserSaldo" (currect balance of the user) and "VerbruikSaldo" (cost of this specific acion of a specific user). As you might guess, the new "UserSaldo" is the old one, plus the "VerbruikSaldo" of this action.

It calculates the "VerbruikSaldo" correctly, but somehow rounds my sum

Example:

Old Usersaldo = 8.00

VerbruikSaldo = 4.20

New UserSaldo = 12.00   (although it should be 12.20...)

```
Dim VerbruikSaldo, UserSaldo As Integer
'verbruik invoegen en saldo herberekenen
VerbruikSaldo = MateriaalPrijs * MateriaalHoeveelheid
Worksheets(UserName).Cells(LastRow + 1, Cdatum).Value = Date
Worksheets(UserName).Cells(LastRow + 1, Cnaam).Value = MateriaalNaam
Worksheets(UserName).Cells(LastRow + 1, Caant).Value = MateriaalHoeveelheid
Worksheets(UserName).Cells(LastRow + 1, Ckost).Value = VerbruikSaldo
UserSaldo = Worksheets(UserName).Cells(LastRow, Ccumul).Value + VerbruikSaldo
MsgBox UserSaldo
Worksheets(UserName).Cells(LastRow + 1, Ccumul).Value = UserSaldo
Worksheets(UserName).Cells(2, 2).Value = UserSaldo
```

There is more code of course... just put in the stuff i thought relevant.
Sorry for the dutch terms ;)

Comment: well you are telling it to do that: `UserSaldo As Integer`.  Declare it as a Double: `UserSaldo As Double`.

Comment: Also with `Dim VerbruikSaldo, UserSaldo As Integer` only declares `UserSaldo` as an integer.  Use `Dim VerbruikSaldo As Double, UserSaldo As Double`

Comment: So... two utterly basic mistakes... Thx alot, works like a charm. Didn't notice these because I worked with inventory stuff before, having no decimals.... Thx!